# Java ArrayList - How do i make one

Tags: java, arraylist

So I want to make an arraylist in a class of its own and add 50 states to it.  Can someone help me figure this out because when i add the arraylist and go states(thats my arraylist name).add("Indiana");  it throws an error.

What do i do

```
public class Phone {
    public Phone(){

    }
     ArrayList<String> phoneType = new ArrayList<String>();
     phoneType.add("home");
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: Are you sure you want a class of its own?  The whole point about having classes like `ArrayList` is so that you don't need a separate class just for storing simple stuff.

Comment: I assume that you've written something like `ArrayList<String> states = new ArrayList<String>();` somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Phone {
    public Phone(){

    }
     ArrayList<String> phoneType = new ArrayList<String>();
     phoneType.add("home");
}
```

Thit doesn't compile cause `phoneType` it's not even in a method or block-initalizer
In order to resolve that you have many options

1) with block-initializer

```
public class Phone{

    private List<String> phoneTypes = new ArrayList<>();
     {
          phoneTypes.add("home");
          phoneTypes.add("mobile");
           .
           .  
     }

}
```

2) in constructor

```
public class Phone {
    private List<String> phoneTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    public Phone(){
      phoneTypes.add("home");
      phoneTypes.add("mobile");
       .
       .
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton....didnt realize I had to make it a method in the class.  Rookie mistake....java 101 i suppose

Comment: @user2939808 i didn't show example using a method.. i made example using `block-initializer` and with `constructor` no method involved.